# Why are my Google results gray?

Tags: google-search

I'm not sure why my google results are displaying gray links.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
Here's the path to the file on my Windows 7 computer: 

C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css 

Simply open the file with Notepad, and paste the following line of code: 
A:visited { color: red ! important } 

Note: You can change "red" to any color you prefer (green, yellow, black, etc). 

Save the file and you're done. 

Keep in mind this is for custom styles, hence the name "Custom.css".
```

So if this is the first time you're modifying this file, it's normal for this file to be blank (no existing lines of code) when you first open it for editing.

I just thought I would share this because I was originally surprised by this.  I guess I shouldn't have been, but I was.`enter code here`

Comment: I'm using a mac. I looked through the "package contents" and I didn't see any similar file. Thanks though.